# backup multiple websites daily automatically

Tags: backup, freebsd

this is my situation
i have a web server pc with many websites in it (using vhost) running freebsd. just in case something bad happened to my server, i want to backup every websites in it every midnight.

my questions are :

1. is it possible to backup many websites with different file name from a single command? 

2. can i store the backup files to my other server via ftp automatically ?

3. or it's better to create a clone server ?? how do i synchronize it's content ??


any clue will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

> 1. is it possible to backup many websites with different file name from a single command?

Yes. You'll just need to write up a bash script to perform the backup.

> 2. can i store the backup files to my other server via ftp automatically ?

Yes. Again, you'll need to do that from within your backup script.

> 3. or it's better to create a clone server ??

Well, that's up to you to decide.

> how do i synchronize it's content ??

That's a very large topic, which would warrant its own question and answers.

There are a bunch of pre-made backup systems for *nix. I'd recommend you check out rsnapshot or rdiff-backup. These will only account for your *files*. For your *databases*, you'll need to research the best way to back those up and implement that separately.